# Connecting to MySQL Database with Aulux Barcode software

Tags: mysql, sql, database-connection, barcode, unicenta

I have a local MySQL Database which stores all the details for my Point of Sale software - Unicenta oPOS. I am able to connect to the database just fine with Unicenta and with my website software.

I am trying to use a piece of software called Aulux Barcode Label Maker 7 to create labels for my products. I cannot seem to get this software to connect to my database. Has anyone done anything similar? Or have any tips that might work?

See attached some screenshots of my Unicenta config which does work and the Aulux which does not. Note that I have tried all different combinations of the host name used in Unicenta, but doesn't seem to matter how I format it...

[Unicenta works fine...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TpsS4.jpg)

[Option chosen for Aulux](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3mIu.jpg)

[Fails to connect. I have tried adding port and such...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfvBf.jpg)

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I had issues myself with this but figured out a way to make it work, hopefully it helps someone else too.

First you need to download the correct [MySQL ODBC connector](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/) for your system.

Once that is done set it up by typing in "Data Sources (ODBC)" in the windows search.

Add the MySQL ODBC Unicode Driver, along with the name e.g. MySQL, IP Server, User, Password & database.

Once that's done you can go into Aulux Barcode Maker and go to Data Table -> Database

Select Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers -> Next

Select your newly created connection e.g. MySQL (Or whatever you named it)

Put in the MySQL username and password but leave the following field blank (catalog to use)

That's it, your done. Hope it helps ;)